# Speed up comparison of floats between lists

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a block of code which does the following:

- take a float from a list, `b_lst` below, of index `indx`
- check if this float is located between a float of index `i` and the next one (of index `i+1`) in list `a_lst`
- if it is, then store `indx` in a sub-list of a third list (`c_lst`) where the index of that sub-list is the index of the left float in `a_lst` (ie: `i`)
- repeat for all floats in `b_lst`

Here's a `MWE` which shows what the code does:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def random_data(N):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(0., 10., N).tolist()

# Data lists.
# Note that a_lst is sorted.
a_lst = np.sort(random_data(1000))
b_lst = random_data(5000)
# Fixed index value (int)
c = 25

def func():
    # Create empty list with as many sub-lists as elements present
    # in a_lst beyond the 'c' index.
    c_lst = [[] for _ in range(len(a_lst[c:])-1)]

    # For each element in b_lst.
    for indx,elem in enumerate(b_lst):

        # For elements in a_lst beyond the 'c' index.
        for i in range(len(a_lst[c:])-1):

            # Check if 'elem' is between this a_lst element
            # and the next.
            if a_lst[c+i] < elem <= a_lst[c+(i+1)]:

                # If it is then store the index of 'elem' ('indx')
                # in the 'i' sub-list of c_lst.
                c_lst[i].append(indx)

    return c_lst

print func()
# time function.
func_time = timeit.timeit(func, number=10)
print func_time
```

This code works as it should but I really need to improve its performance since it's slowing down the rest of my code.

---

**Add**

This is the optimized function based on the accepted answer. It's quite ugly but it gets the job done.

```
def func_opt():
    c_lst = [[] for _ in range(len(a_lst[c:])-1)]
    c_opt = np.searchsorted(a_lst[c:], b_lst, side='left')
    for elem in c_opt:
        if 0<elem<len(a_lst[c:]):
            c_lst[elem-1] = np.where(c_opt==elem)[0].tolist()
    return c_lst
```

In my tests this is ~7x faster than the original function.

---

**Add 2**

Much faster not using `np.where`:

```
def func_opt2():
    c_lst = [[] for _ in range(len(a_lst[c:])-1)]
    c_opt = np.searchsorted(a_lst[c:], b_lst, side='left')
    for indx,elem in enumerate(c_opt):
        if 0<elem<len(a_lst[c:]):
            c_lst[elem-1].append(indx)
    return c_lst
```

This is ~130x faster than the original function.

---

**Add 3**

Following [jtaylor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633169/jtaylor)'s advice I converted the result of `np.searchsorted` to a list with `.tolist()`:

```
def func_opt3():
    c_lst = [[] for _ in range(len(a_lst[c:])-1)]
    c_opt = np.searchsorted(a_lst[c:], b_lst, side='left').tolist()
    for indx,elem in enumerate(c_opt):
        if 0<elem<len(a_lst[c:]):
            c_lst[elem-1].append(indx)
    return c_lst
```

This is ~470x faster than the original function.

Comment: eww, lists - did you consider numpy? eww, forloops - did you consider numpy? Serious now: what are the dimensions of all your things? is the 200 and 1000 just for dummy purposes to explain here? or are those the real sizes?

Comment: Yeah I know but lists and for loops are the dirty fast way of coding in my case. After that is the stage of performance improving. As for your question they can grow a bit, say 1000/5000, but I don't expect them to grow much more beyond that.

Comment: numpy is the clean fast way of coding - as soon as you get used to it, you will nearly never use lists anymore, and as soon as you learn to (ab)use the slicing, you will never use for-loops anymore either

Comment: @usethedeathstar the OP may be implying: "how can I do this stuff with numpy?"

Comment: @zhangxaochen yes I am. usethedeathstar I'm in the _getting used to it_ stage. I do know what slicing is but I don't manage it enough to translate this block into numpy arrays.

Comment: @zhangxaochen keeping the zen of python in mind: explicit is better than implicit (that goes for questions on stackoverflow too)  note: this is not intended as an offensive comment, i just want to say: if you want to know how to do this in numpy, explicitly ask for a pure numpy solution, because if i look at your random-method, i could deduce that you want to avoid numpy and go all out for lists, since you convert those random data to a list instead of keeping it as a numpy array

Comment: you can get more performance out of your `func_opt2` by converting the searchsorted result back to a list with .tolist(), scalar operations with numpy types have a pretty high penalty

Comment: @jtaylor that's a very good tip. I tried and I get a ~3.5x speedup compared to the next faster function `func_opt2`. I'll add this to the question, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take a look at numpy's [`searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Calling

```
np.searchsorted(a_lst, b_lst, side='right')
```

will return an array of indices, the same length as `b_lst`, holding before which item in `a_lst` they should be inserted to preserve order. It will be very fast, as it uses binary search and the looping happens in C. You could then create your subarrays with fancy indexing, e.g.:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 10)
>>> b = np.random.rand(100) * 10
>>> c = np.searchsorted(a, b, side='right')
>>> b[c == 0]
array([ 0.54620226,  0.40043875,  0.62398925,  0.40097674,  0.58765603,
        0.14045264,  0.16990249,  0.78264088,  0.51507254,  0.31808327,
        0.03895417,  0.92130027])
>>> b[c == 1]
array([ 1.34599709,  1.42645778,  1.13025996,  1.20096723,  1.75724448,
        1.87447058,  1.23422399,  1.37807553,  1.64118058,  1.53740299])
```

Comment: Jaime, I'm not sure how I should apply this to my code. I need a list of indexes from the `b_lst` stored in the `c_lst` not floats.

Comment: In that case, you want to use `np.where(c == 0)`, `np.where(c == 1)`, `np.where(c == 2)`, ...

Comment: Ok, got it now. I'll update the question with what I could come up with following your answer. It's ugly and I'm pretty sure it could be optimized even further but it's a first step. Thanks!