# Filling a list faster

Tags: python, arrays, performance, list, numpy

I have a small block of code which I use to fill a list with integers. I need to improve its performance, perhaps translating the whole thing into `numpy` arrays, but I'm not sure how.

Here's the `MWE`:

```
import numpy as np

# List filled with integers.
a = np.random.randint(0,100,1000)

N = 10
b = [[] for _ in range(N-1)]
for indx,integ in enumerate(a):
    if 0<elem<N:
        b[integ-1].append(indx)
```

This is what it does:

- for every integer (`integ`) in `a`
- see if it is located between a given range `(0,N)`
- if it is, store its index in a sub-list of `b` where the index of said sub-list is the original integer minus 1 (`integ-1`)

This bit of code runs pretty fast but my actual code uses much larger lists, hence the need to improve its performance.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do. You code looks like there _should be_ a more straight-forward way to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: probably you need generators or itertools. but i agree with @Carsten. explain what your goal is. Btw b could be defaultdict(list)

Comment: Just for fun, the one-liner for the sorting logic is `b = [np.where(a == i) for i in range(1, N)]`.

Comment: @Carsten I could explain what this block is meant to do but it would take a couple of pages. This is a tiny block of code buried deep inside a much larger (thousands of lines) code I'm working on and it does a very minor thing. That's why I left out all things that would complicate it unnecessarily and posted it as simple as possible. For more context, I'm coming from this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856907/speed-up-comparison-of-floats-between-lists and I'm now trying to improve the performance of the function mentioned in **Add 2**.

Comment: @Carsten darn missed that one-liner, might add a [0] on the np.where though?

Comment: @Gabriel Concerning "I could explain what this block is meant to do but it would take a couple of pages.". The Zen of Python says " If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.".

Comment: @Hyperboreus the implementation is straightforward to explain, the _code_ itself is not. I've added a small explanation of what the block does in the question.

Comment: It looks like all he wants to do is get the indices where an array is equal to a set of integers. The one-liner by @Carsten (with an additional `[0]` after the call to `np.where`) is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @deinonychusaur Right, thanks, I missed that.

Comment: I suppose if you're really desperate for speed you could try doing it in Cython, but that seems like it would just complicate things at this point.

Comment: The one-liner by @Carsten using `np.where` is ~3x slower than the original code. Not sure why, I'd suppose using `numpy` would be faster but it's apparently not.

Comment: That's odd. I'm getting a speedup of around a factor of 20 on the example code. I guess it would depend on how large `N` is when compared to the size of `a` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution! The first half I shamelessly stole from Joe's answer, but after that it uses sorting and binary search, which scales better with `N`.

```
def new(a, N):
    mask = (a > 0) & (a < N)
    elements = a[mask]
    indices = np.arange(a.size)[mask]

    sorting_idx = np.argsort(elements, kind='mergesort')
    ind_sorted = indices[sorting_idx]

    x = np.searchsorted(elements, range(N), side='right', sorter=sorting_idx)

    return [ind_sorted[x[i]:x[i+1]] for i in range(N-1)]
```

You could put `x = x.tolist()` in there for an additional albeit small speed improvement (NB: if you do an `a = a.tolist()` in your original code, you do get a significant speedup). Also, I used `'mergesort'` which is a stable sort but if you don't need the final result sorted, you can get away with a faster sorting algorithm.

Comment: I did some tests and indeed this version is much faster than the original one or Joe's version. Only in one case this version did worse than the original (using `1000` for `a` and 10000` for `N`) but the rest of the tests I performed it was significantly faster. I'm sorry Joe but I'll have to switch to this one as the accepted answer. Thank you very much for the code @moarningsun!

Comment: Yes @Gabriel, your original "algorithm" is simply the most efficient. Only by taking the long way around with a convoluted "algorithm" you can tap into the speed of Numpy and achieve a speedup overall, for the right sizes of `a` and `N`. Ideally you would use the original algorithm and speed it up using e.g. Cython or Numba (not sure how well this would turn out though).

Comment: @Gabriel - No worries, this is a much better answer!

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
mask = (a > 0) & (a < N)
elements = a[mask]
indicies = np.arange(a.size)[mask]

b = [indicies[elements == i] for i in range(1, N)]
```

If we time the two:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,100,1000)
N = 10

def original(a, N):
    b = [[] for _ in range(N-1)]
    for indx,elem in enumerate(a):
        if 0<elem<N:
            b[elem-1].append(indx)
    return b

def new(a, N):
    mask = (a > 0) & (a < N)
    elements = a[mask]
    indicies = np.arange(a.size)[mask]

    return [indicies[elements == i] for i in range(1, N)]
```

The "new" way is considerably (~20x) faster:

```
In [5]: %timeit original(a, N)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.21 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit new(a, N)
10000 loops, best of 3: 57 us per loop
```

And the results are identical:

```
In [7]: new_results = new(a, N)

In [8]: old_results = original(a, N)

In [9]: for x, y in zip(new_results, old_results):
   ....:     assert np.allclose(x, y)
   ....:

In [10]:
```

The "new" vectorized version also scales much better to longer sequences. If we use a million-item-long sequence for `a`, the original solution takes slightly over 1 second, while the new version takes only 17 milliseconds (a ~70x speedup).

Comment: Great answer @Joe, thank you very much. Just to check, could you confirm that for large values of `N` (say `a = np.random.randint(0,100,5000)` and `N=1000`) this answer is actually slightly slower than the original code?

Comment: @Gabriel - Woops, yes, you're right. I get slightly faster times for the original function for large values of `N` and lengths of `a` in the low-thousands. For very long `a`'s, the "new" function becomes faster again, though.  I don't see any way to get any further speedup, though.  Good luck!